# error in linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

The program takes input before asking for it. The problem starts after we input the value for first node.

This is a simple program which takes input from user and stores it in a linked list and then displays the data stored.

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct NODE
{
    int data;
    struct NODE* next;
};

void main()
{      
    struct NODE  *first,*old,*new_node;
    int n,i;
    printf ("Enter number of elements: \n");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    first=(struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    first->next= NULL;

    printf ("Enter value of node 1: \n");
    scanf ("%d\n",&first->data);
    old = first;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        new_node=(struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
        new_node->next= NULL;

        printf("Enter value of node %d: \n",i);
        scanf("%d\n",&new_node->data);
        old->next=new_node;
        old = new_node;
    }

    old=first;
    while(old!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \t",old->data);
        old=old->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could clarify the exact issue.

Comment: Show us the output

Comment: @anuj shrivastav It seems like you are looking for singly link list. Have you googled on same ? And where is your head node?Why loop starting from i=2? Why can't you create first node from within loop?

Comment: @TusharSharma i've used first as head node

Comment: @anuj shrivastav what is the input you are giving?

Comment: @TusharSharma https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJaCA.jpg

Comment: The proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). **note:** `main` is a function of `type int` and it returns a value. See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup (draft n1570)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). See also: [See What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: "problem starts after we input the value for first node."  and `scanf ("%d\n",&first->data);` --> `scanf ("%d",&first->data);`  Drop the `'\n'`  - 2 places.

Comment: Try to think for few minutes how to describe your problem. We aren't mind readers, so "error in linked list in C" doesn't tell anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `\n` in your [scanf format specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications), which contains (with my emphasis):

> There are rarely constants (i.e. characters that are not formatting
>   placeholders) in a format string, mainly because a program is usually
>   not designed to read known data. **The exception is one or more
>   whitespace characters, which discards all whitespace characters in the
>   input.**

So your `\n` means that the new-line that you input after each number is ignored, and the next `scanf()` doesn't complete until you have typed *another* new-line (you correctly omit it from the first node count input).

All you need to do is to remove the `\n` from the format strings and your code will work as you expect:

```
    ...
    scanf ("%d\n",&first->data);
    ...
    scanf("%d\n",&new_node->data);
    ...
```

Note that you can input on the same line as the prompt by omitting the `\n` from the `printf()` format strings and calling `fflush(stdout)` before calling `scanf()`, eg:

```
    printf ("Enter number of elements: "); 
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf ("%d",&n);
```

This will give you a more natural dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

you can peroform all linked list operations like this

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    struct Node *next;
    int data;

};

void printList(struct Node *n)
{
  while (n != NULL)
  {
     printf(" %d ", n->data);
     n = n->next;
  }
}

void insertFirst( struct Node *start,int data1)
 {
        struct Node *n=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        n->data=data1;
        n->next=start->next;
        start->next=n;
 }

void insertLast( struct Node *start,int data1)
 {
    struct Node *last,*previous;
    last=start->next;
    while(last!=NULL)
    {
        previous=last;
        last=last->next;    
     }
        struct Node *n=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        n->data=data1;
        n->next=NULL;
        previous->next=n;
 }

void insertPosition(struct Node *start, int pos, int data1)
{
    int count=0;
    struct Node *node;
    node=start->next;
    while(node!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        node=node->next;
    }
    printf("total elements before insertion is %d\n ",count);

    if(count+1<pos)
    printf("cannot insert at desired position ");
    else
    {
     int i=1;
     node=start;
        while(i<pos)
        {
            node=node->next;
            i++;
        }

      struct Node *n=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      n->data=data1;
      n->next=node->next;
      node->next=n;
}
}

void deleteFirst(struct Node *start)
{
    struct Node *firstNode;
    firstNode= start->next;
    start->next=firstNode->next;
    free(firstNode);
    printf("first node is removed\n");
}

void deleteLast(struct Node *start)
{
    struct Node *last,*previous;
    last=start;
    while(last->next!=NULL)
    {
        previous=last;
        last=last->next;    

     }
        previous->next=NULL;

    free(last);
    printf("last node is removed\n");
}     

void deletePosition(struct Node *start, int pos)
{
    int count=0;
    struct Node *node;
    struct Node *previous;
    node=start->next;
    while(node!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        node=node->next;
    }
    printf("total elements before deletion is %d\n ",count);

    if(count<pos)
    printf("cannot delete the desired position ");
    else
    {
     int i=1;
     node=start->next;
        while(i<pos)
        {
            previous=node;
            node=node->next;
            i++;
        }

      previous->next=node->next;
      free(node);
        printf("node is removed\n");

}
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *start=NULL;
    struct Node *node1=NULL;
    struct Node *node2=NULL;
    struct Node *node3=NULL;
    struct Node *node=NULL;

    start=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));    
    node1=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node2=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node3=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));


    start->next=node1;
    node1->data=1;
    node1->next=node2;

     node2->data=2;
    node2->next=node3;

     node3->data=3;
    node3->next=NULL;
    printf("\nsize %d\n",sizeof(struct Node));


    //insertFirst(start,10);
    //insertLast(start,200);
   // insertPosition(start,2,300);

    // deleteFirst(start);
  //  deleteLast(start);
  //deletePosition(start,2);
     printList(start->next);
}
```

comments can be removed to perform that operation.

Comment: I believe the OP wishes to know about what is wrong in his own code. Your answer does not address OP's issue at all.

Comment: yes, but this code is solution of OP's problem as well as additional feature to help him.

Comment: Neither have you used the same layout as the OP nor the same functions or parameters. No offence meant but if the OP wanted already written code , a Google search would have done it.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ya you are absolutely right but if you save the program in .cpp formate(C++) it will cause error. Thats why I did this